# Google chrome removal after deleting /opt/google

Tags: apt, package-management, google-chrome

I had installed google-chrome and there was a folder named google in /opt.
For some reason I accidentally removed /opt.
Now I have trouble removing google-chrome-stable with apt-get.
Any ideas on how to completely remove it from the system?

`sudo apt-get remove` or `sudo apt-get purge` fails with:

```
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

Does the removal of all folders associated with google chrome and then somehow remove it from the dpkg list of installed packages sufficient enough for it to be completely removed from the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a wrong way to manually remove any files or folders installed by dpkg.

The solution is to re-install google-chrome via a deb package.

Download deb file from `google.com`, then install it using

```
sudo dpkg -i <file_name>
```

then remove it

```
sudo apt-get purge google-chrome*
```

Comment: I get the same error when trying to reinstall as with the one while trying to remove or purge it.

Comment: How do you-reinstall?

Comment: Have tried both 
  sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable  and
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall.
Both give the same error as the one in the question.

Comment: You will have to download deb file and install. See my answer.